# CSS. Можно ли скрыть div, если он содержит элемент с определенным классом?

Tags: css

Есть такая структура

```
<div class="upload-status">
<span class="icon"></span>
</div>
```

При загрузке документа на `span` навешивается доп. класс `icon-success`

Можно ли как то через `CSS` задать условие, что если в `upload-status.icon` нет класса `icon-success` - то применить `display: none` ?

Это легко сделать через `JS`, но мб есть варианты обойтись без него?

Comment: Нельзя, CSS не умеет "смотреть назад"

Comment: Селектор `:has` https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:has для этих целей ждут уже много лет. Последнее время пошли обсуждения и какие-то подвижки есть, но пока ни в каком браузере он ещё не реализован для обычных пользователей.